# How to push a content state to a current editor state? editorState.push method seems not work for me?

Tags: draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

there are some plain text content need to insert to exist textEditor, I try to use EditorState.push method, what I think it's work for the situation.
I try something like this:

```
const { ContentState: { createFromText }, EditorState: { createWithContent, push }} = DraftJS;
export const pushTextToCurrentEditorState = (text, editorState) => {
    const textContentState = createFromText(text);
    const newEditorState = push(editorState, textContentState, 'insert-characters');
    // debugger;
    console.log(editorStateToJSON(editorState))
    console.log(editorStateToJSON(newEditorState))
    return JSON.parse(editorStateToJSON(newEditorState));
}
```

result is `newEditorState` is not the merge state ,but replace one, older editorState miss, `newEditorState` become brand new thing like create from the `text`.
Is here something wrong usage? or there are some other ways to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I tired a complex way but solve this problem. code here:

```js
export const pushTextToCurrentEditorState = (text, editorState) => {
 
    const textContentState = createFromText(text);
    const textContentBlocksArr = textContentState.getBlocksAsArray();
    const currentBlocksArr = editorState.getCurrentContent().getBlocksAsArray();
    const newBlocksArr = currentBlocksArr.concat(textContentBlocksArr);
    const newContentState = createFromBlockArray(newBlocksArr);
    const newEditorState = createWithContent(newContentState);

    return JSON.parse(editorStateToJSON(newEditorState));
}
```

way:
1. convert content state, text, to blocks array;
2. combine two blocks array together;
3. create new content state and editor state with combined array;

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem perfectly :)